# Login issue on NEWGEN Omnidocs 7.0 Document Management System

Tags: authentication

we have a Newgen Omnidocs 7.0 Document Management System installed in Server A, with two modules: one for Admin and the other for normal users activities.
Application uses MSSQL as Backend Database installed in Server B
Previously if we are having any issue on the application, all we do is restart the Omnidocs Services (JBOSS,Wrapper,SMS) on SERVER A, and all is fine. But there has been no Login issues before.

When we try to login on the platform:
The One for users activities (http://SERVER A:8080/omnidocs/login.jsp) shows the error below:
This account has been locked. Please contact your Administrator.

The One for Admin activities (http://SERVER A:8080/omnidocs/admin/login.jsp) shows the error below:
Error: Invalid login information.

Any user account used shows same errors.
Using unknown or invalid user account credentials also show same errors

On checking the Database UserSecurity Table for some of the Users and Admin credentials used:
LoggedInAttempts shows '0';
UserLocked shows 'N';
LastLoginTime shows a date and time before the issue of not able to login started;
LastLoginFaliureTime shows 'Null';
FailureAttemptCount shows '0'

I came to the conclusion that there might be a disconnect somewhere between the application and the database, but I don't know where, or what might be the cause, since for over five (5) or more years of the application. this is the first time we are witnessing such issue.

I have restarted all Servers, MSSQL database, All Omnidocs Services, yet no resolution.
The Technical partners who installed the application has moved on to other things, and could not be of any help.
The Staff who has been in charge of the application has moved on too, and said she has not encountered that kind of issue since the launch of the application.

Please, any help for speedy resolution will be appreciated. Thanking you all for your support in advance.

Edit:
I have been digging deep everywhere (God knows where...) on the Server A that host the Omnidocs application, trying to find a clue to this issue. I went to the location of the log files where  omnidoc was installed (C:\Program Files )x86)\Omnidocs 7.0\Wrapper\Omnidocs_logs), and found something odd in one of the log files (Client_Exception.log) I noticed an exception that has never occur since 2015 until 1st February 2022 at about 10am. And subsequently till today(5 days after)its appearing at intervals daily non stop. Below is the exception. Pls whoever has a quick fix should help me out while I move around here to read those with same exception and figure out how they relate to mine and try resolving it.:

[02 Feb 2022 00:57:32,481 : DEBUG] -

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.newgen.omni.jts.txn.NGOClientServiceHandlerHome not bound
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:443)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor317.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at org.jnp.server.NamingServer_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:610)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:572)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at com.newgen.omni.jts.client.NGOEjbApi.ngoExecuteCall(NGOEjbApi.java:125)
at com.newgen.omni.jts.client.NGOXMLCallBroker.routeCall(NGOXMLCallBroker.java:140)
at com.newgen.omni.jts.client.NGOXMLCallBroker.jumpToFunction(NGOXMLCallBroker.java:89)
at com.newgen.wrapper.NGTimeOut.getListOfCabinets(NGTimeOut.java:73)
at com.newgen.wrapper.NGTimeOut.run(NGTimeOut.java:94)
```

[02 Feb 2022 00:57:32,481 : DEBUG] - Category : 1
Message : Object Is Not Registered On Server.
ExceptionCode : -1042
Generator : NGOEjbApi : NGOGetListOfCabinets
Recoveryinfo :

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what i wrote above was that we were unable to login to our omnidocs application with the error i wrote above: invalid login and account has been locked error messages, I was trying to find out what could make an application that has been installed and used for  close to 10yrs suddenly refused to allow login no matter the account ID you used. but we are good now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were finally able to resolve the login issue. After deducing that it was a case of missing file or files, and not able to pinpoint the actual file that was missing for close to two weeks, we decided to do a Windows Server backup restoration from a backup that was done on the 30th of January. The issue was resolved after the restoration, and we were able to login to Ominidocs without any further issues.